# angular 8 elements disappearing after post request

Tags: php, angular, typescript

I'm a beginner in angular , i was trying to establish a connection with database using php as backend programming language , it was working fine and the elements were showing from database but when i inserted them to the database , it does work and they are inserted to the database but my elements disappear when the form is submitted and when the form is submitted again they flash for seconds .

**MY HTML CODE**

```html
<form (submit)="loginUser($event)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="User name" id="name" >
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="pass">
    <button type="submit" >Log in</button>
    {{name}}
    </form>
    <ul *ngFor="let item of datas ">
        <li>{{item.name}} {{item.pass}}</li>
    </ul>
```

**MY LOGIN.COMPONENT FILE**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { iEmployee } from '../../empolyee';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private Auth:AuthService) { }
  public datas;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.Auth.getUserDetail().subscribe(data=> this.datas=data);
  }

  loginUser(event: { preventDefault: () => void; target: any; }){
      event.preventDefault();
    const target = event.target;
    const name=target.querySelector('#name').value;
    const pass=target.querySelector('#pass').value;
    this.Auth.createuser(name,pass).subscribe(data=>this.datas=data);
    this.Auth.getUserDetail().subscribe(data=> this.datas=data);

  }
}
```

**MY AUTH.SERVICE FILE**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { iEmployee } from '../empolyee';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
private url : string='http://localhost:81/example/Angular/php/display.php';
private url2:string='http://localhost:81/example/Angular/php/addNew.php';
getUserDetail() {
return this.http.get(this.url)          
}
createuser(name , pass) {
  return this.http.post(this.url2,{name,pass},{
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
});
}
}
```

**MY ADDNEW.PHP FILE**

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 

include 'connection.php';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
$name= $data['name'];
$pass= $data['pass'];
$sql="insert into test(name,pass) values ('$name','$pass')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);  


?>
```

Comment: Does your browser console show any errors after you submit the form? What exactly flashes, is it the the data that's supposed to appear in your `ngFor` loop? Could you also provide sample `console.log` output for both the `createuser()` and `getUserDetail()` functions (add a `console.log` in the subscribe function for each call in your login component file)

Comment: yes the data must appear in ngFor disappeared and flashes on re-submitting  .and i did an console.log in the subscribe function and for createuser() it prints null .

Comment: thanks for pointing this out , i took the condition out of subscribe function for createuser() and now it works fine .